# ListView unable to add and edit cell when empty

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to use a `ListView` as an Editor for Strings, that come out of a custom data model. I use `TextFieldListCell`s with an appropriate `StringConverter` for the cells.

There is an add button next to the `ListView` that calls this method on action:

```
@FXML
private void addElement() {
    WordListItem newItem = new WordListItem(-1, "");

    wordListItems.add(newItem);
    wordListView.setEditable(true);
    wordListView.getSelectionModel().select(wordListItems.indexOf(newItem));
    wordListView.edit(wordListItems.indexOf(newItem));
    wordListView.setEditable(false);
}
```

Where `wordListView` is the `ListView` and `wordListItems` is the `ObservableList` containing the data for the `wordListView`.

This does work, except for when the list is empty (not null), and I couldn't quite explain why, so I inspected the Java source code for help.

Here's what I found out so far: the `edit(int)` call on `ListView` changes the `ListView`s internal `editIndex` value, which is supposed to call the `EDIT_START` `Event`. The `editIndex` is an `ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper` in which I found some weird code that I can't quite understand and I'm not sure if thats actually producing a bug or I just can't see why they did it:

```
@Override
protected void fireValueChangedEvent() {
    super.fireValueChangedEvent();
    if (readOnlyProperty != null) {
        readOnlyProperty.fireValueChangedEvent();
    }
}
```

This method is called whenever the `editIndex` property of `ListView` is changed. The problem: `readOnlyProperty` is null, because it's not set anywhere. The only place I could find where it got set is in the getter:

```
public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty getReadOnlyProperty() {
    if (readOnlyProperty == null) {
        readOnlyProperty = new ReadOnlyPropertyImpl();
    }
    return readOnlyProperty;
}
```

(`ReadOnlyIntegerImpl` is an inner private class and `readOnlyProperty` is it's type)

---

**Now to my actual question:** Is this a bug or am I overseeing something? Is there a reason why I can't add and edit a newly created Element in my list like that when it's empty, or is it really just this getter not being called yet?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700005/javafx-listview-add-and-edit-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code you found just is code for lazy initializing the property.

Unless new value is assigned to the property or the property itself is requested, `null` can be used as the property to avoid unnecessary creation of property objects. This is not an issue here.

The issue seems to be the `ListView` cells not being updated before `edit` is called. This happens during layout, so "manually" calling `layout` before starting the edit should work:

```
private void addElement() {
    WordListItem newItem = new WordListItem(-1, "");

    wordListItems.add(newItem);
    wordListView.setEditable(true);

    wordListView.layout();

    wordListView.edit(wordListItems.size()-1);
    wordListView.setEditable(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `wordListItems.size()-1` makes sense and was like that before I started trying to debug.
that weird line, selecting the line that is being edited is actually a workaround for an _actual_ bug I found.